# Poisson Regression in R with individual fixed-effects and month/year fixed-effects

Tags: r, poisson, longitudinal

I'd like to use a fixed-effect **Poisson Regression model** to examine whether opting into 2 different schemes (specified as dummies in my model) can lead to increased exercise. 
I have **longitudinal** data, over a timespan of 3 years (data measured on a monthly basis), with **N=100,000+** (each ID having varying amounts of observations/months tracked). IDs can opt into the two different schemes at any point, they can opt into one only (Scheme 1) or into neither, or into both either simultaneously or at different points in time (Scheme 1 and then Scheme 2).

I'd like to include individual fixed-effects (using within-individual variations in the opting into the two different schemes).
I also want to include month/year fixed-effects to control for time trends/seasonality in exercise patterns. I am thinking of using a set of dummy variables for each specific month in a given year for this.

I'd like to specify my model as the following:

> y(i,my) = Λ(i) + γ(my) + βScheme1(i,my) + βScheme2(i,my) + ε(i,my)

So **y(i,my)** refers to the dependent variable level of exercise performed by ID i at month m in year y.

**Λ(i)** is the individual-specific fixed-effect.

**γ(my)** is the time fixed-effect.

Scheme 1 and Scheme 2 respectively take the value 1 if the **ENT** i has opted into the scheme at and after month m.

FYI: Really sorry, I've had to put what each variable is defined with respect to in parenthesis in the equation above

Below is what I initially ran using the `glm()` function just including Schemes 1 and 2 as dependent variables and that worked fine.

```
PoissonModel <- glm(DepVar ~ Scheme1 + Scheme2, family = poisson, data = dataset)
```

My issue is I am unsure how to write the code/what to do in order to include the **Λ(i)** and **γ(my)** in my regression too. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: If you are fine with including them directly as dummies, convert the time variable and ID variable into factors using `factor` or `as.factor`, then include them in your formula.

Comment: If you really want a 'within' estimator, try the `pglm` package.

Comment: Hi Imo, thank you for your comments. I tried changing time variable and ID variable as factors and then including them in my formula however I keep getting the following error:
Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)

Will try use pglm package as you suggest in 2nd comment, thanks!

Comment: The fixest package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fixest) would likely do the trick and do it quicker than `pglm`.